# Python/Windows, prevent subprocess (external program) from displaying popups

Tags: python, windows, hide, subprocess

Python 2.7

OS: Windows (program will ALWAYS work on Windows so cross compatibility isn't an issue )

I'm forced to use external application as a part of an validation process and i'm having troubles hidding the popup windows which come as an output of this external program.

Basically i do this:

```
    args = [ "-A" + param_a, "-B" + param_b, "-C" + param_c ]

    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess._subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
    startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess._subprocess.SW_HIDE

    process = Popen(["C:\external_app.exe", args[0],args[1],args[2]], startupinfo=startupinfo, shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

    (output, err) = process.communicate()
    exit_code = process.wait()
    print exit_code
```

The code works, but when there is an missing parameter, or parameters are not valid, the external program outputs a popup window with a corresponding message and an "OK" button, that needs to be clicked on to continue.

In the code I also included all my attemps to prevent *that* from happening.

I know there must be a way to disable this behaviour, because program can work as independent windows task and isn't interrupted by any of these messages.

Maybe there is a way of emulating this in Python or in Windows itself ? 
Or perhaps there is a way to auto-confirm all incomming dialog-popups of an application?

Any solution would do.

Thanks,
Piotr

PS. I also tried contacting original author of this app but the company isn't even there... Also tried to guess an optional parameter like -hidden etc. but without any luck.

Comment: The python process can invoke the binary i.e in this case external_app.exe but it cannot change the behavior of the external binary. From behavior I mean the dailog pop ups for wrong parameters.

Comment: Your best option will be using an automation tool as AutoIT or AutoHotKey, starting a parallel script to monitorize if the popup window shows, and then clicking the button.