# Windows: disable 'Program not responding' popup

Tags: python, windows, popen, kill

I have a program that is being launched with a python script via `subprocess.popen()`.

The program is killed when it does not do what it is supposed to in 20 seconds.

When the program takes longer it means that it is not responding and that is perfectly fine in my situation.

Now the program is begin killed just fine with `p.kill()` but that annoying popup still persists:

---

[image]

---

Question: is there a way to prevent these kinds of pop ups and if so how do I do it ?

Question 2: apart from being annoying, do these popups take up resources ? mind you the process is killed, and theoretically pressing the debug option should go nowhere, I'm asking because I plan on leaving this machine over the weekend to do some computations, and I don't want this to affect the computation time at all.

Comment: 1) What does this popup translate to in English? 2) Can you show some essential code that achieves this result? 3) You can use the [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) library in Python to capture debug messages.4) To monitor performance you can use the [Windows Sysinternals Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) tool.

Comment: @user8212173 popup says "process not responding" gives option to debug or to close process 2) code is irrelevant since this is issue with windows I have, process is being launched with subprocess.popen("cmd", shell=False) 3)what woudl I do with logging ? 4) I dont need performance monitoring, I need that window to go away

Comment: You may find some help in this [similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047245/python-windows-prevent-subprocess-external-program-from-displaying-popups).